# How to customize SharePoint 2010 mobile view

Tags: mobile, branding

I am stuck on developing a mobile view for my SP2010 publishing portal. It is Internet-facing with custom pages / web parts (e.g. `http://server/Pages/customPage.aspx` with custom webparts on it). The site has a custom master page.

I am having the following issues with the built-in mobile functionality:

1. The welcome page. Navigating to
   `http://server/?Mobile=1` redirects me
   to
   `http://server/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx`, which just shows a table of lists / document libraries available. For
   my portal, I want to show a
   dashboard, just like I currently do for the "normal" non-mobile view.
2. Navigating to one of my custom
   pages (e.g.
   `http://server/Pages/customPage.aspx?Mobile=1`)
   also redirects to
   `http://server/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx`.

So in effect there is really no helpful built-in mobile support at all; just the ability to view lists with a mobile device.

---

So I have a number of issues and I'm hoping for some high-level help. My thought is that I should do the following tasks:

1. Create a separate master page for mobile
2. Figure out how to choose this master page based on "is client a mobile device?"
3. Figure out how to prevent the redirection to /_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx

Then I think the mobile site will operate similarly to the normal site.

What do you think? Am I on the right track?

---

This is a [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896708/how-to-customize-sharepoint-2010-mobile-view) with Stack Overflow; I realize this site is more specific to SharePoint, but SO has a bigger community so I do not find it redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Randy Drisgill has an [article](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-6-mobile-browsers.html?) about mobile views.  Basically any smartphone should be able to view the site normally.  You just need to manipulate the App_Browsers compat file.

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\portal.contoso.com80\App_Browsers\compat.browse
>
> This file has settings for MANY popular browsers, including most
>   mobile browsers. In my example I want to change the mobile setting for
>   the iPhone browser so I found this section:

```
<!-- iPhone Safari Browser --> <!-- sample UA "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U;
 CPU iPhone OS 2_0 like Mac OS X; ja-jp) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML,
 like Gecko) Version/3.1.1 Mobile/5A345 Safari/525.20" --> <browser
 id="iPhoneSafari" parentID="AppleSafari"> <identification> <userAgent
 match="iPhone" /> <userAgent match="Mobile" /> </identification>
 <capabilities> <capability name="isMobileDevice" value="true" />
 <capability name="canInitiateVoiceCall" value="true" /> <capability
 name="optimumPageWeight" value="1500" /> <capability
 name="requiresViewportMetaTag" value="true" /> <capability
 name="supportsTouchScreen" value="true" /> <capability
 name="telephoneNumberDetectionDisabled" value="true" />
 </capabilities> </browser>
```